# Generalization of the Payley-Zigmund inequality

Tags: probability, random-variable, probability-inequalities, inequality

The Payley-Zigmund inequality states that for a positive random variable $Z$ the following holds
\begin{equation}
\operatorname{P}( Z > \theta\operatorname{E}[Z] )
\ge (1-\theta)^2 \frac{\operatorname{E}[Z]^2}{\operatorname{E}[Z^2]}.
\end{equation}
I wonder if there exists similar results for a bidimensional positive random variable $\vec{Z} = (Z_1,Z_2)$, $Z_{1,2} \geq 0$ in terms of the first and second moments of the variable(s)
\begin{align}
\operatorname{E}[Z_1], \operatorname{E}[Z_1], \operatorname{E}[Z_1^2], \operatorname{E}[Z_2^2], \operatorname{E}[Z_1 Z_2]
\end{align}

Comment: Could you indicate what kind of generalization you have in mind, given that there cannot exist any total ordering of multivariate values?  What might you be hoping for beyond applying the P-Z inequality to the marginal distributions?